# I want to send data to a new screen without navigating to it on pressing a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send data to different screen on pressing a button.
I am using

```
Get.to(Screen(), arguments: [data])
```

I only want to send data
It send the data but also navigate to it
Please give me. Some. Hint

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have two Stateful widget class.

The **CheetahInput** has a static variable **data** that will get data from any class And
we have a check on **TEXT()** when variable **data** is empty simply show **"old value"** in **TEXT()** widget
if variable **data** is not empty then show its value on **Text()** widget.

```
 class CheetahInput extends StatefulWidget {
     Static String? data;
    
      @override
      _CheetahInputState createState() => _CheetahInputState();
    }
    
    class _CheetahInputState extends State<CheetahInput> {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(child: Text(SignIn.data!=null?SignIn.data!:'old value'),); }
    }
```

The **TestEditor** Class has **saveButton** and **navigatebutton**, while the **savebutton** will assign data into static variable "**data**" in **SignIn** class,
And the **NavigateButton** will Navigate to that screen where you have sended the data

```
 class TestEditor extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TestEditorState createState() => _TestEditorState();
    }
    
    class _TestEditorState extends State<TestEditor> {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       
        return Scaffold(        
          body: Container(),
          floatingActionButton:Container( width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: Row(
            children: [Spacer(),
              FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>SignIn(context)));},child: Text('NavigateButton'),),
              Spacer(),
    FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){SignIn.data='I am data from new page';},child: Text('saveButton'),),Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

}
```

So in this way, you send data to other screens without navigate to that screen at meantime